# create table from two existing table by making the index column and value not match in both table

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, command-line

for this table1 structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
   `table_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `firstname` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column2` varchar(32) default NULL,
   `column3` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column4` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column5` varchar(56) default NULL,
   `column6` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column7` varchar(36) default NULL,
   `column8` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column9` varchar(40) default NULL,
   `column10` varchar(86) default NULL,
   `column11` varchar(113) default NULL,
   `column12` varchar(50) default NULL,
   `column13` varchar(50) default NULL,
   `column14` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column15` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column16` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column17` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column18` varchar(25) default NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`table_id`),
       KEY `firstname` (`firstname`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13982 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
   `table_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `firstname` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column2` varchar(32) default NULL,
   `column3` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column4` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column5` varchar(56) default NULL,
   `column6` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column7` varchar(36) default NULL,
   `column8` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column9` varchar(40) default NULL,
   `column10` varchar(86) default NULL,
   `column11` varchar(113) default NULL,
   `column12` varchar(50) default NULL,
   `column13` varchar(50) default NULL,
   `column14` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column15` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column16` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column17` varchar(25) default NULL,
   `column18` varchar(25) default NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`table_id`),
       KEY `firstname` (`firstname`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13982 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

after this executing this below query and its giving timeout expired in code.

```
 CREATE TABLE new_tablematch 
    select table_id, firstname 
       from table1 
          where firstname NOT in (select a.firstname 
                                  from table1 as a , table2 as b 
                                  where a.firstname= b.firstname);
```

Comment: You say "timeout expired in code"... what code? What happens if you run the query directly in mysql?

Comment: [**It is working fine here.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56632a/1) Note that there is a small typo in the `CREATE TABLE` statements the extra `,` in the last column definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tablematch 
SELECT table1.table_id, table1.firstname 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.firstname = table2.firstname
WHERE table2.firstname IS NULL;
```

It should have a better performance than your query (you are referring to table1 twice, and the subselect might be executed for every row of table1).

Comment: if the tables are large, it might help to put indexes on the firstname columns

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that you mention `table1` twice.  It is not needed in the subquery:

```
 CREATE TABLE new_tablematch 
    select table_id, firstname 
    from table1 
    where firstname NOT in (select b.firstname 
                            from table2 as b
                           );
```

However, the `join` version in the other answer might perform even better.